# Orthogonal vectors in the positive cone of $\Bbb R^m$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

What is the meaning of the statement " $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n$ are orthogonal vectors in the positive cone of $\Bbb R^m$". I have encountered that in a book.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on which book and what the book is about it? It would help in giving you the definition which is most useful to you

Comment: Which part of this sentence is unclear?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely we're looking at the set $$C = \{ {\bf x} \in \Bbb R^m \mid x_1^2+\cdots+ x_{m-1}^2 = x^2_m \ \mbox{  and  } \ x_m >0 \},$$and we're taking ${\bf v}_1,\cdots,{\bf v}_n \in C$ (we can pick these vectors being orthogonal to each other if $n \leq m$, just intersect $C$ with convenient hyperplanes).

Think about it in $\Bbb R^3$ first to gain intuition.